# Jquery image in div, makes the code act strange

Tags: jquery

Hey there, third related question to this code, hopefully the final one:).

This code seems to work pretty smooth:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".photo").mouseenter(function() {

 $(this).html('<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,24,0" width="170" height="125"><param name="movie" value="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="flashvars" value="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto" /><embed src="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" width="170" height="125" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" flashvars="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto"></embed></object>');
});

$(".photo").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).html('ffff');
});
```

The problem is .photo div (i have 10 different divs)

If photo div is empty, or has plain text inside, everything works fine.
BUT, if i have a photo inside photo div, which on mouseenter will be replaced with the flash movie, everything brakes, the movie isn't loaded properly and it isn't replaced promptly with "fff" on mouseleave.

The link is to an adult site, unfortunately I can't provide this here as it is against the rules and may be considered offensive and unsuitable for all audiences.

Thank u!

If i delete everything inside .photo, the above code works perfectly. If a live the link, it works to.. only if i put an image, it brakes the code.

PS. here is the html code, it's on wordpress index.php

```
<div class="section"><!-- Start Section -->

<div class="photo"><!-- Start Photo -->
    <div class="transparency"></div>
    <div class="performer"><p><? echo $perf; ?></p></div>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<? echo ''.$perf.''; ?>'s bio - <? echo ''.get_the_title().''; ?>"><img src="<? echo ''.$pic.''; ?>" width="180" height="135" alt="<? echo ''.get_the_title().''; ?>" style="display:block"/></a>
</div><!-- End Photo -->

<div class="left"><!-- Start left -->
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<? echo ''.$perf.''; ?>'s Bio Page and Live Cam">Bio Page</a>
</div><!-- End Left -->

<div class="right"><!-- Start Right -->
    <a href="the linkx" target="_blank" title="Free Chat with <? echo ''.$perf.''; ?> " rel="nofollow">Free Chat</a>
</div><!-- End Right -->
```

Comment: You're right, those kinds of links might get you banned here. I've edited it out instead of flagging on this occasion since your question is genuine enough.

Comment: Your problem may lie in using a class as oppose to unique IDs, if you have multiple divs with the same class, on that action on one you are applying it to all, hence the wackiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kid of solved it;) Added hoverIntent, things started to get screwy when I changed the mouse to fast from one div to another. 
Thax